# How to edit WoW models with Blender?

Tags: blender, export, import, world-of-warcraft-modding

My situation is following, I am into role play, mostly me and my friends are using World of Warcraft. Since I am a bit into Blender too, I would like to try to edit some models(armor and weapon) for private use only(!). Problem is - I have no idea how to import and export them.

So far I have found only this [forums.runicgames](http://forums.runicgames.com/discussion/58367/tutorial-wow-weapons-armor), but it looks very outdated, and I am not sure if it will work with Warlords of Dreanor extension.

How would I go about exporting the models from WoW and importing them into Blender?